# SELECT e INSERT - Inserindo apenas o primeiro dado

Tags: php, sql

Queria que salvasse os dois dados (de_setor e para_setor) distintos porém ele tá salvando apenas o primeiro nos dois

Script de inserção (html):

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="de_setor" class="w3-text-black">Do setor de:</label>
    <select class="form-control" required id="de_setor" name="de_setor">
        <option value=""disabled selected hidden>Selecione...</option>
        <?php
            while($linha = $pegadiv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        ?>
            <option name="<?= $linha['setor_id'] ?>"> <?= $linha['setor'] ?> </option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>


    <label for="para_setor" class="w3-text-black">Para o setor de:</label>
    <select class="form-control" required id="para_setor" name="para_setor">
        <option value=""disabled selected hidden>Selecione...</option>
        <?php
            while($linha2 = $pegadiv2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        ?>
            <option name="<?= $linha2['setor_id'] ?>"> <?= $linha2['setor'] ?> </option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Script de inserção (php):

```html
$acao  = (isset($_POST['acao'])) ? $_POST['acao'] : '';
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$requerente = $_POST['requerente'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$de_setor = (isset($_POST['de_setor']));
$para_setor = (isset($_POST['para_setor']));
$informe = $_POST['informe'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$informante = (isset($_POST['informante']));
$processo_id = (isset($_POST['processo_id']));

 if ($acao == 'incluir'){
    $processos = "INSERT INTO processos(numero, assunto, requerente, status)VALUES(:numero, :assunto, :requerente, :status)";
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($processos);
    $stm->bindValue(':numero', $numero);
    $stm->bindValue(':assunto', $assunto);
    $stm->bindValue(':requerente', $requerente);
    $stm->bindValue(':status', $status);
    if($stm->execute()){
        
        $lastid = $conexao->lastInsertId();
        $informes = "INSERT INTO informes(de_setor, para_setor, informe, data, informante, processo_id)VALUES (:de_setor, :para_setor, :informe, :data, :informante, :processo_id)";
        $tsm = $conexao->prepare($informes);
        $tsm->bindValue(':de_setor', $de_setor);
        $tsm->bindValue(':para_setor', $para_setor);
        $tsm->bindValue(':informe', $informe);
        $tsm->bindValue(':data', $data);
        $tsm->bindValue(':informante', $informante);
        $tsm->bindValue(':processo_id', $lastid);
        if ($tsm->execute()){
```

BD:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: como você ta salvando o formulário? como você recupera os valores dos campos do formularios? Tente retornar o "$para_setor". Veja se ele está vindo certo do form

Comment: ué? to salvando com o script de inserção em php. **all_processo.php**.

é em pdo

Comment: $para_setor = (isset($_POST['para_setor']));  está retornando certo?

Comment: creio que sim, afinal o problema não é no processo de inserção e sim no select que puxa o </option> do banco de dados.

      <label for="de_setor" class="w3-text-black">Do setor de:</label>
      <select class="form-control" required id="de_setor" name="de_setor">
      <option value=""disabled selected hidden>Selecione...</option>
      <?php
      while($linha = $pegadiv->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      ?>
      <option value="<?= $linha['setor_id'] ?>""<?= $linha['setor'] ?>"></option>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
      </select>

Comment: o problema está aqui :<option value="<?= $linha['setor_id'] ?>""<?= $linha['setor'] ?>">  dessa forma ele só vai enxergar o setor_id , pois o outro está fora do escopo

Comment: ou você concatena ou você cria um outro atributo que o receba

Comment: como eu concatenaria isso essa linha?

Comment: se puder me ajudar, ficarei grato!

obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está em ao invés de `name` deve usar `value` em ambos os `<select>`:

```
<option name="<?= $linha2['setor_id'] ?>"> <?= $linha2['setor'] ?> </option>
```

Mas podem ser:

**1ª**

```
<option value="<?php echo $linha2['setor_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $linha2['setor']; ?> </option>
```

**2ª**

```
<select class="form-control" required id="de_setor" name="de_setor"> 
    <option value=""disabled selected hidden>Selecione...</option> 
    <?php while($linha = $pegadiv->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$linha['setor_id'].'">'.$linha['setor'].'</option>';
    }?> 
</select>
```

Comment: agora tá dando esse erro: Notice: Undefined index: setor in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\registrarprocesso.php on line 122

Comment: editei a resposta

Comment: agora não tá puxando os dados.
eu abro o selecione, no formulário mesmo, e só aparece um dado em branco.

Comment: Nenhuma das duas opções q eu dei? 1ª tbm ta editada

Comment: a 1° aparece o undefined index, já a 2° é o dado em branco

Comment: por favor, se puder me ajudar ficarei grato!